# php including broke after testing on live environment

Tags: php, apache, cpanel

I'm having trouble launching my php web-app to the cloud ( shared-hosting )

My web-app works on localhost ( windows environment ) without errors or warnings,
but when I try running it on linux ( ubuntu based distro ) - cPanel to be specific including/requiring functions aren't finding the files they were suppose to open.

example
Directory Structure

```
app/
|
|__ index.php
|__ include_me.php
|_(folder1)|
           |_ helloworld.php
```

in `index.php`

```
<?php 

echo "1 2 3..";
require("folder1/helloworld.php");
?>
```

in `helloworld.php`

```
<?php 
# code...
include("include_me.php")
?>
```

in include_me.php

```
<?php
echo "Hello, I've been included";
?>
```

this code was working on localhost ( WINDOWS )
but it breaks on linux environment

I think the reason is the `include_path`

It's different on windows and Linux:

`On Windows`

```
Include_path SET TO => "A:\apps\php\PEAR"
```

On Linux

```
Inlcude_path SET TO => ".:/opt/alt/php72/usr/share/pear"
```

I've also tried to run it from a VPS to see if the issue is only on Shared hostings, and still didn't work

Ubuntu

```
Include_path SET TO => ".:/usr/share/php"
```

How can I fix it ?

UPDATE :

Video that shows the code works at localhost
https://streamable.com/wxvv2c

index.php is including helloworld.php into index.php then the helloworld.php code execute on index.php that's why it's finding the file, but if I added `../` in helloworld.php then

when index.php includes helloworld.php now the code inside helloworld.php will run on index.php so now index.php can't find ../include_me.php

Comment: `Inlcude_path` !== `Include_path`

Comment: HI, If you load include_me.php from inside helloworld.php, which is not on the same level, you have to update the path to include_me.php : include( '../include_me.php')

Comment: _this code was working on localhost_ It can't, because `helloworld.php` never will find `include_me.php` the way you coded it.

Comment: Answering @RiggsFolly:
Inlcude_path appears as an error as show in the img 
https://imgur.com/Xkd6kJp

Comment: Answering @Dexter0015:

I'm including helloworld first from the index.php then the helloworld.php get included at index.php and from there the index.php will start looking for that include_me.php file and include it 
if i added the ../include_me.php on helloworld.php then the file will not be included.

Comment: Answering @Michel:

How it can't work i've tested it and it did work 

index.php request the file helloworld.php then the helloworld.php content loads at index.php after loading then the script inside the helloworld.php will execute inside 
index.php and look for that file starting at index.php

Comment: If you want the code I can sent it to you or even better i'll show you by recording the results

Comment: https://streamable.com/wxvv2c

Comment: I've tested on Linux but can't reproduce. Tested on Linux and Windows are works fine.

Comment: In your helloworld.php, add this code `var_dump(stream_resolve_include_path('include_me.php'));` to debug how is it resolved to full path. It looks like not possible that your index file will not echo out **1 2 3..** because it is called before `require`.